# how to create a surface in matlab using interpolation

Tags: matlab

I have x y z data which looks like the following:

[image]

How do i create a surface across the lines using z values in matlab (interpolated surface)?

I tried this method but i am getting following error:

```
[fn,pn] = uigetfile('*.xyz','Open the file');
I = importdata([pn,fn], ',', 16);



x = I.data(:,1);
y = I.data(:,2);
z = I.data(:,3);





%%
spX = min(x):3:max(x);
spY = min(y):3:max(y); 

[xC,yC] = meshgrid(spX,spY);


Vq = interp2(x,y,z,xC,yC);
```

Error using griddedInterpolant
The grid vectors must be strictly monotonically increasing.

Error in interp2>makegriddedinterp (line 229)
    F = griddedInterpolant(varargin{:});

Error in interp2 (line 129)
        F = makegriddedinterp({X, Y}, V, method,extrap);

Comment: did you checked the [interp2](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html#btyq8s0-2_1) documentation? there is an example exactly like that. You have `[x,y,z]` data and interpolate using the `interp2` function to get a finer mesh and plot with `surf`.

Comment: i updated the question tried the mentioned method but it is giving error

Comment: without seeing your actual data, it is difficult to elaborate more, but provided `x` and `y` are vector (as in your code `x = I.data(:,1);`), then your `z` variable should be a matrix containing length(Y) rows and length(X) columns. To transform your data, you could try to do [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/54029-how-to-transform-a-xyz-array-into-a-xxy-matrix-with-z-as-values-of-each-mxy-component-and-vice-versa) or use the File Exchange [xyz2grid(https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/56414-xyz-file-functions) function.

Answer (score 0):

Try **griddata**

```
spX = min(x):3:max(x);
spY = min(y):3:max(y); 

[xC,yC] = meshgrid(spX,spY);

zC = griddata(x,y,z,xC,yC);
surf(xC,yC,zC)
```